Fluentd throwing error Net::ReadTimout when flushing buffer
we are setting up a fluentd aggregator on a VM to aggregate logs from OpenShift pods and sending the message to Splunk. We have the plugins installed.
However upon running, we encounter the following error:
2024-10-24 01:24:50 +0000 [debug]: #0 [to_splunklog] taking back chunk for errors. chunk="62495299dd305f0c9c9266f1d0d518b1" 
2024-10-24 01:24:50 +0000 [warn]: #0 [to_splunklog] failed to flush the buffer. retry_times=0 next_retry_time=2024-10-24 01:24:52 +0000 chunk="62495299dd305f0c9c9266f1d0d518b1" error_class=Net::ReadTimeout error="Net::ReadTimeout"

The config on the buffer is as below:
<buffer>
  @type file
  #max size of each chunk.by default when chunk reaches 95% it will flush out. to change the % use #chunk_full_threshold
  chunk_limit_size 5m
  #size limitation of this buffer plugin instance. if reaches full all append operation will fail
  total_limit_size 390g
  #Limit the number of queued chunks
  queued_chunks_limit_size 16
  #The number of threads to flush/write chunks in parallel
  flush_thread_count 16
  flush_mode interval
  flush_interval 3s
  flush_thread_burst_interval 1s
  flush_at_shutdown true

  retry_forever true
  retry_wait 1s
</buffer>

Was trying to search for that error online but mostly is on ElasticSearch and not due to Splunk. Any information / help on this error? Thank you
